# Which side up (with skin or not) to put a salmon slice when microwaving?

Tags: fish, microwave, salmon

It is a quick meal only of course but still interesting how better. There are raw salmon slices available for sale here. They are flat and have a skin on one side, that can be either upper or lower side. I cook them in microwave, just with salt and few slices of onions underneath.

It generally works not so bad (preparation speed is valuable for me), but every time I do this I am thinking should I put the slices skin top or skin bottom to the cooking dish onto the onions. Or does not have any impact?

Comment: Curiosity: you're microwaving the salmon on top of raw onions? For how long?

Comment: Since you do this frequently, it sounds like the perfect opportunity to test it both ways to see if there are any differences.  You are welcome to then answer your own question.

Comment: @Luciano 15 to 20 minutes. The onions are fine after this. Some fat goes out that I do not want to lose (rich in omega acids that are good) so gets captured into onions.

Comment: How powerful is the microwave? Not that I've ever microwaved salmon, but that sounds far too long. I can't imagine it wouldn't be done in 3, or less.

Comment: If the point is to have the juices escape into the onion i would think skin up is the way to go. Probably also helps trap any moisture that turns to steam too. But i don't microwave salmon so that's a guess.